# What does the CT suffix stand for in voltage regulator?

Tags: voltage-regulator, lm78xx

Given a regulator such as the LM7812, what does the CT suffix stand for in a voltage regulator in Fairchild [LM7812CT](https://www.fairchildsemi.com/products/power-management/voltage-regulators/positive-voltage-linear-regulators/LM7812.html))?

I've googled and went through the related [datasheets](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/149/LM7812-1010875.pdf), but could not find the answer to this.

Comment: You probably need to look at the accompanying notes in the "general info" chapter in the databook, but C probably refers to Commercial temperature range, and T will be a code referring to the package (TO220 vs TO3 or SOT223 etc). C will be pretty general across manufacturers, package codes maybe less so. Also, LM denote a National Semiconductors (now TI) part, (with Fairchild now ON) as a second source, so look at TI for a datasheet that may have more info.

Comment: See page 23 here http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm7812.pdf

Comment: If you're talking about a *distributor* part number, rather than a manufacturer part number, a "CT" suffix frequently means that the part is being supplied on "cut tape"  -- I.e., cut from a full reel of parts.

Comment: @BrianDrummond Looks to me like it means TO-220 on p. 23.

Comment: @BrianDrummond, Except that they use the same "CT" suffix for both -40 to +125 C and 0 to +125 C rated parts (the narrower range for the tighter tolerance version). And TI's datasheet isn't going to give insight into the suffixes used by Fairchild. Since "CT" is the only suffix offered, it doesn't really matter much what they mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part number suffixes are decided somewhat arbitrarily by each manufacturer. Often the refer to either different temperature ranges the parts are specified over, or to the package the part is provided in.

But in this case, the part is only available in one package (TO-220), and with one suffix (CT), so there's no way to know. Nor does it really matter, since you can't choose any other suffix from this vendor.

Maybe by looking at other Fairchild parts, you could find a pattern. Second source parts from other manufacturers will have different suffixes, so their datasheets won't help you know what the Fairchild suffix means.

If there were different suffixes available, you would usually be able to work out their meaning from the "Ordering Information" table, on page 1 of the dataseheet in this case. For example, if you look at the Fairchild [KA78xx datasheet](https://www.fairchildsemi.com/datasheets/KA/KA7805E.pdf), you'll see that for that part family an "ETU" suffix indicates TO-220 package, while "RTF" or "RTM" suffix indicates DPAK.